# Highcharts semi-pie - remove space between pie and legend

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts, pie-chart

I'm struggling with the [semi circle donut](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-semi-circle) chat of Highcharts. I'm trying to reduce the gap between the bottom of the donut and the legend below, without success.

Here is the basic chart I'm working on :

https://jsfiddle.net/vmw0pekL/2/

And the result is :

[image]

This is the basic graph without so many customization. What I tried next is to play with the `marginTop` and `marginBottom` chart properties. I managed to reduce the space between the graph and the legend but now I have a huge gap at the top of the chart... Here's the result :

https://jsfiddle.net/vmw0pekL/3/

And the result is :

[image]

Do someone know how to deal with this issue ? I'd like to get no space on top on the graph, and no space between the graph and the legend.

Comment: Do more trials and add height to chat. See https://jsfiddle.net/vmw0pekL/4/

Comment: One more example using `marginBottom` only.  http://jsfiddle.net/foLqaLpc/

Comment: @Deep3015 Thanks, I managed to play a bit more and get what I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why there is a big blank gap below the semi circle donut chart, is because this space is reserved for the lower part of the full pie chart (change startAngle to 0 and endAngle to 360 to see what I mean). You can change that by setting a new values for the `center` array and by setting a new `size` of the pie.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.pie.center

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/327uxkbt/

Answer (score 0):

this is one easy way of doing it :

```
chart: {
    marginTop: 10,
    marginBottom: -150,
    marginLeft: -100,
    marginRight: -100
},

#container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 240px;
  font-size: 8px;
  width: 370px;
}
```